# CSS Transform (rotation) causes text flicker in Safari 8 (yosemite)

Tags: css, safari, gpu, safari8

That's was an issue with safari 7 and it was fixed by the following code

```
-webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
-moz-backface-visibility:    hidden;
-ms-backface-visibility:     hidden;
```

Now it's not fixed in Safari 8. It causes text flicker

link http://jsfiddle.net/6x9u11c9/1/

Comment: I'm having the same issue with the Scale property. I think it's just down to Apple to fix this, nothing I've tried works.

Answer (score 1):

I still haven't found a perfect solution for this problem. I have the same problem on Firefox (Yosemite).

Adding:

```
-webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
-webkit-filter: opacity(1);
```

to the body 'fixed' it a little. The font doesn't flicker anymore but it does become less 'bold'.

EDIT:
Adding these to the body fixed the problem in Safari for me. It still occurs in Firefox as it is not a webkit browser.

`-webkit-filter: opacity(.9999);
-webkit-text-stroke: 0.35px;`